# How would I write a loop or function that makes the numbers shake with each mouse click

Tags: javascript, css, loops, animation, css-animations

I created a basic javascript counter. And I would like to apply a transform scale to each number every time the counter is clicked. (essentially everytime I click the counter, i want the numbers to slightly grow then return to the base size).

I cant figure out how to loop this so that it happens everytime I increment or decrement.

here is my code:

```
let addButton = document.querySelector(".btn-add");
let subButton = document.querySelector(".btn-lower");
let num = document.querySelector("h3");
let start = 0;
let colorChange = () => {
    if (start > 0) {
        num.classList.add("positive");
    } else if (start < 0) {
        num.classList.add("negative");
    } else {
        num.classList.remove("positive");
        num.classList.remove("negative");
    }
};



addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    start++;
    num.innerHTML = start;
    colorChange();
    
});
subButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    start--;
    num.innerHTML = start;
    colorChange();
});
```

here is the animation I would like to add

```
.wiggle {
    animation: shake 250ms ease-in-out;
}

// h3 {

// }
@keyframes shake {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    70% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `animationend` event to remove the wiggle class each time and add it in the colorChange()

```js
let addButton = document.querySelector(".btn-add");
let subButton = document.querySelector(".btn-lower");
let num = document.querySelector("h3");
let start = 0;

// remove wiggle class when the animation is done
num.addEventListener('animationend', function(){
  this.classList.remove('wiggle')
});



let colorChange = () => {
    if (start > 0) {
        num.classList.add("positive");
    } else if (start < 0) {
        num.classList.add("negative");
    } else {
        num.classList.remove("positive");
        num.classList.remove("negative");
    }
    num.classList.add('wiggle')
};


addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    start++;
    num.innerHTML = start;
    colorChange();
    
});
subButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    start--;
    num.innerHTML = start;
    colorChange();
});
```

```css
.wiggle {
    animation: shake 250ms ease-in-out;
}

// h3 {

// }
@keyframes shake {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    70% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.positive{color:green}
.negative{color:red}
```

```html
<h3>0</h3>
<button class="btn-add">+</button>
<button class="btn-lower">-</button>
```